# QTP Link object does not support the Exist property

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a weird problem with QTP 11. The following piece of code worked so far, but suddenly stopped working and throws Object does not support this property or method.: 'objPage.Link' for the line with 'if link exist'

```
Set objBrowser = Browser("creationtime:=" & Desktop.ChildObjects(oDesc).Count - 1 & "")
Set objPage = objBrowser.Page("title:=.*")
If objPage.Link("class:=menu_link_tab_.*", "html id:=.*DesktopTab").Exist(3) Then
   msgbox "ok"
End If
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and/or how to do it right?

EDIT: I solved this but still have no idea what happened. I just cut this part from QTP script and pasted it into Notepad and then copied it from Notepad to QTP. Everything works fine. I did not change anything... Any ideas what the hell happened are welcomed.

ANOTHER EDIT: The problem reappears randomly. With no changes to anything I can just run the test 10 times to have it fail randomly with the 'Object does not support this property or method' message

I have a startBrowser function where I set the objPage and objBrowser :

```
Function startBrowser(vURL)
   Dim oDesc
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   IE.Visible = True
   IE.Navigate vURL
   Window("hwnd:=" & IE.HWND).Maximize
   Set oDesc = Description.Create
   oDesc( "micclass" ).Value = "Browser"
   If Desktop.ChildObjects(oDesc).Count > 0 Then
       Set objBrowser = Browser("creationtime:=" & Desktop.ChildObjects(oDesc).Count - 1 & "")
   End If
   Set objPage = objBrowser.Page("title:=.*")
End Function
```

I have added lots of msgboxes with GetROProperty to verify whether the objects are ok. They seem to be.

Now my function to click the link looks like this :

```
Function clickMainMenuLink(vIdentifier)
   Set objLink = objPage.Link("class:=menu_link_tab_.*", "html id:=.*" & vIdentifier, "index:=0")
   If objLink.Exist(timeOut) Then
       objLink.Click
       Else
       reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Click the " & vIdentifier & " menu link", "Cannot find the " & vIdentifier & " menu link"
       ExitTestIteration
   End If
End Function
```

So at the moment my test just opens the browser and clicks a link as I try to debug the thing, but it still fails or passes randomly. The run error indicates line with 'Set objLink'. Any ideas for further debugging? I'm on QTP11 and IE8 if it matters.

Comment: You say it worked so far, what has changed? Have you changed versions of QTP/browser?

Comment: The open browser/log in part was moved from function to reusable action. It is the part that is setting the objBrowser and objPage. The If is called in the script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Motti, your reasoning was right. The problem was with the objPage part. Despite the fact that I could read every property of objPage in a function QTP sometimes just did not see this objPage as a Page object. I guess it has something to do with not declaring type explicitly, but that's just a guess. As a dirty workaround I set up the objBrowser and objPage in every function now and it works 100%.

Comment: So why didn't you accept Motti's answer, but created your own and accepted that one?

Answer (score 1):

From your error *does not support this property or method: `objPage.Link`* it would appear that the problem isn't with the `.Exist` part of line but the `.Link` part (you can verify this by separating the line into two lines and see which fails

```
set objLink = objPage.Link("class:=menu_link_tab_.*", "html id:=.*DesktopTab")
If objLink.Exist(3) Then
```

From your comment it seems that you're creating `objPage` in a different location from where you're using it, I suggest making sure that the object arrives OK.

Comment: This was my first guess. I am triple checking that objBrowser and objPage elements are correct. They are.
As I mentioned in the edit, I did copy the link.exist line to notepad and pasted it back to qtp and this solved the problem. I have no idea what was the reason though as the copy pasted line is exactly the same as it ever was...